# Show Test result Form test suites using TFS api

Tags: tfs-sdk, microsoft-test-manager, test-suite

I am working with a school project where I am going to analyse a companies defect database.
They are using Microsoft Foundation Server (TFS).
I am all new to TFS and the TFS api.

I have some problem in getting the right data from TFS using the TFS Client Object Model
.
I can retrieve all Test Plans, their respective test suites and every test case that a specific test suite uses, but the problem comes when I want to see in which test suite I have a specific test result from a test case. Since more than one the suite can use the same test cases, I cant see in which suite the result came from.

I am doing this way in getting test cases from suites:

```
foreach (ITestSuiteEntry testcase in suiteEntrys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t \t Test Case: {0}", testcase.Title+", "+"Test case priority: "+ testcase.TestCase.Priority+"Test case Id: "+testcase.TestCase.Id);
    //Console.Write(", Test Case: {0}", testcase.ToString());

    //get each test result:
    getTestResult(testcase,proj);
}

private void getTestResult(ITestSuiteEntry testcase, ITestManagementTeamProject proj)
{
    var testResults = proj.TestResults.ByTestId(testcase.TestCase.Id);
    foreach (ITestCaseResult result in testResults)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t \t \t"+result.DateCreated+","+result.Outcome);
    }
}
```

So my question is, how can I see the Test Suite which was used to execute the test?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, since I haven't delved into this part of the API in recent days, but I remember that the `ITestPoint`/`TestPointId` actually links the  test result to the test suite.

Comment: This blogpost might help you forward as well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/densto/archive/2010/03/04/the-test-management-api-part-2-creating-modifying-test-plans.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at following code snippet.
It shows you how to get *Test Results* for a specific *Test Suite* using *Test Points Ids*.
You can use similar approach to achieve your goal.

```cs
var tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
        new Uri(tfsUrl),
        new System.Net.NetworkCredential(<user>, <password>));
tfsCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

var testManagementService = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
var teamProject = testManagementService.GetTeamProject(projectName);
var testPlan = teamProject.TestPlans.Find(testPlanId);

// Get all Test Cases belonging to a particular Test Suite.
// (If you are using several Test Configurations and want to take only one of them into account,
// you will have to add 'AND ConfigurationId = <your Test Configuration Id>' to the WHERE clause.)
string queryForTestPointsForSpecificTestSuite = string.Format("SELECT * FROM TestPoint WHERE SuiteId = {0}", suiteId );
var testPoints = testPlan.QueryTestPoints(queryForTestPointsForSpecificTestSuite);
// We are going to use these ids when analyzing Test Results
List<int> testPointsIds = (from testPoint in testPoints select testPoint.Id).ToList();

var testResults = teamProject.TestResults.ByTestId(testCaseId);

var testResultsForSpecificTestSuite = testResults.Where(testResult => testPointsIds.Contains(testResult.TestPointId));
```

This blog post will help you when creating queries: [WIQL for Test](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/duat_le/archive/2010/02/25/wiql-for-test.aspx)

Comment: I get nullpointerexception on testManagementService. Any Ideas why?

Comment: @mosaad Please provide more information. Do you mean you get a NullReference exception? When do you get it?

Comment: I fixed it, just incase someone has the same problem I forget to change the url from the base url to one of the collections and so it could not find the test management service