# Using the TFS TestManagementHttpClient how can I get access to the Suite Entry

Tags: c#, tfs, httpclient

I am using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi 14.0 and trying to get a list of test results for an iteration.

I can get some of the information from the WebApi but I still have to revisit the old Tfs Api to get other bits.

Does anyone have a full example using WebApi that does not need to use ITestManagementService and TfsTeamProjectCollection, or is the new WebApi deficient.

Comment: What's the detail of "other bits" in your case? Did you just mean you want to use TFS web API to get test results for a specific test suite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must to say, actually there are some difference between the library **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client** and **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WebApi.Client**. The mainly is that Client libraries (SOAP API) use [Legacy Client Object Model](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/architecture/extend-vs-for-alm) while WebApi libraries calls the New [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) to achieve the functions. In some area,  the WebApi library is providing only a limited functionality - for instance: check in changes with Version Control

> And there are also some limitation with these two APIs:
>
> 1. Client libraries cannot work well with the new vNext build system.
> 2. WebApi cannot perform update action with Version Control, it can only read information for now.

More related info please refer this blog: [NuGet packages for TFS and Visual Studio Online .NET client object model](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2015/08/10/nuget-packages-for-tfs-and-visual-studio-online-net-client-object-model/)

And to get test results for a specific test suite you need to use the old API, a sample link：[Show Test result Form test suites using TFS api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732992/show-test-result-form-test-suites-using-tfs-api)